# Latex on Fedora: Glossary with Xindy

Tags: pdftex, linuxfedora

I'm trying to generate the glossary using `makeglossaries` on Fedora. I installed also `clisp` related packages. But I get the following error:

```
$ makeglossaries HistoryNotes
makeglossaries version 2.19 (2016-05-27)
added glossary type 'main' (glg,gls,glo)
xindy  -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M "HistoryNotes" -t "HistoryNotes.glg" -o "HistoryNotes.gls" "HistoryNotes.glo"
/usr/lib64/clisp-2.49+/base/lisp.run: initialization file `/usr/bin/xindy.mem' was not created by this version of CLISP runtime

***Call to xindy failed***

Check 'HistoryNotes.glg' for details
```

I do not think that the error is related to my `.tex` file, but with the packaging of the `texlive-xindy-*`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[xindy,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\begin{document}

[...]

\newglossaryentry{computer}
{
  name=computer,
  description={is a programmable machine that receives input,
               stores and manipulates data, and provides
               output in a useful format}
}

\printindex
\glsaddall
\printglossary[title=List of Terms,toctitle=Terms and abbreviations]

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{History} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

If I execute `xindy --version`, I get:

```
$ xindy --version
xindy release: 2.5.1
xindy script version: 1.18
/usr/lib64/clisp-2.49+/base/lisp.run: initialization file `/usr/bin/xindy.mem' was not created by this version of CLISP runtime
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Who says this is a Fedora problem?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I do not think that Fedora has a problem. Perhaps the package `texlive-xindy` has, I don't know.

Comment: What happens if you run `xindy --version` directly from a terminal?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: I added the result to the question

Comment: It looks like it's a problem with the `xindy` installation not a problem relating to `glossaries`.

Comment: @LiPo `texlive-xindy` is a Fedora package. It is up to Fedora to declare dependencies so that `texlive-xindy` is installed with the versions of libraries it needs. Either you have forced installation of one or more packages, ignoring `dnf`'s warnings, or this is Fedora's problem. But you do not have installed the correct version of the library required. Hence, `texlive-xindy` is installed without a required dependency. That's a packaging problem i.e. Fedora's or a user problem i.e. forcing things which ought not be forced. (Or you've fiddled in directories best left to `dnf`.)

Comment: The corresponding bug report can be found here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1469512

Answer (score 1):

The package `texlive-xindy` must have some problem.

**Solution**

1. Remove the standard package
2. Download the source code and compile it:

   ```
   wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/indexing/xindy/base/xindy-2.5.1.tar.gz  
   tar zxf xindy-2.5.1.tar.gz  
   cd xindy-2.5.1
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the package `texlive-xindy` requires a different version of `clisp` than the one which is provided by the standard `clisp` package and therefore has to be rebuilt.

An alternative approach to the one given by [@LiPo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/126271/lipo) is to rebuild the package from the source provided in the repositories. This can be done using the follwoing steps:

1. Remove the package `texlive-xindy`

   ```
   sudo rpm -e --nodeps texlive-xindy
   ```
2. Dowload the source package

   ```
   dnf download --source texlive-xindy
   ```
3. Install the dependencies

   ```
   sudo dnf builddep texlive
   ```
4. Rebuild the package(s)

   ```
   rpmbuild --rebuild texlive-<version details>.fc<fedora version>.src.rpm
   ```

   Note that `<version detaills>` and `<fedora version>` should be changed according to the downloaded file
5. Install the rebuilt package

   ```
    sudo dnf install ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/texlive-xindy-bin-<package details>.fc<fedora version>.1.noarch.rpm
   ```

   Note that `<package detaills>` and `<fedora version>` should be changed according to the generated package file. Also note that the location of the package files can be changed by adding a paramater to the package generation command.

The above steps work for Fedora, for other distros the commands will be different but a similar workflow should exist.