# xindy not working in TeXLive - xindy kernel not found

Tags: texlive, xindy

I am using TeXLive 2016 on Fedora 25 and it seems that my installation of `xindy` is not working properly. Whenever it is called, it returns

```
xindy: Could not execute xindy kernel: No such file or directory
```

The call

```
xindy --version
```

returns

```
xindy release: 2.5.1
xindy script version: 1.18
xindy: Could not execute xindy kernel: No such file or directory
```

Does this mean I have to install the xindy kernel separately? In case I have to do this, how can this be done?

Comment: Is this the repository version of TeX Live or a vanilla install?

Comment: It is the repository version. If possible, I would prefer to keep it.

Comment: Looking through the source, this error message is printed if xindy can't find the `clisp` interpreter. Do you have it installed?

Comment: @SergeiGolovan: This seems to be the root of the problem. After I installed it, `xindy --version` returns `/usr/lib64/clisp-2.49+/base/lisp.run: initialization file `/usr/bin/xindy.mem' was not created by this version of CLISP runtime`

Comment: Then I guess, you'd have to rebuild *xindy* from the source.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan: Do you want to summarize your comments into an answer so that I can accept it? Since the `xindy` error message is not very informative, I think this could be of interest for other people as well. After installing `clisp` the problem seems to be the same as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355609/latex-on-fedora-glossary-with-xindy).

Comment: Yes, I've found that answer as well. Okay, I'll write an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xindy` uses GNU CLISP interpreter internally, so it has to be installed along with the `xindy` script (written itself in Perl). If `xindy` can't find `clisp` (or `clisp.exe` for the case of Windows) it emits the following error message:

```
xindy: Could not execute xindy kernel: No such file or directory
```

This means that `clisp` has to be installed.

After that there can be the message

```
/usr/lib64/clisp-2.49+/base/lisp.run: initialization file /usr/bin/xindy.mem' was not created by this version of CLISP runtime
```

This means that `xindy` itself has to be rebuilt from its source. Also, I'd report a bug in `xindy`'s packaging if it's been installed as a binary.

Comment: How to rebuild `xindy` can be found in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355609/latex-on-fedora-glossary-with-xindy).

Comment: I encountered this problem when packaging it for GNU Guix; since on that system everything can be explicitly referenced, I ended up patching the `$clisp` Perl variable in the `user-commands/xindy.in` file.